# Travis CI environment variables with Gradle properties

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci, sonatype

How can I use travis-ci env variables as Gradle's properties?

I locally have my gradle.properties under the gradle path having:

```
sonatypeRepo = abcd
```

Which is used in my `build.gradle`:

```gradle
uploadArchives {   
    //more     
    repository(url: sonatypeRepo) {
        // more
    }
    //more
}
```

Of course locally it works. In travis I have added the variable under settings so I see the build log:

```
Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export sonatypeRepo=[secure]
```

And it fails like:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/home/travis/build/Diolor/Swipecards/library/build.gradle' line: 49
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':library'.
> No such property: sonatypeRepo for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

---

How can I use the Travis' env variable as a Grable property **but** also have the local build as it?

Comment: Is Travis' env variable set as env variable? I would try `def repo = sonatypeRepo ?: System.getenv('sonatypeRepo')`. The first part should work locally, the second on Travis.

Comment: @Opal travis' bash exports it, so it should be available. I tried `repository(url: sonatypeRepo ?: "$System.env.sonatypeRepo") {}` without success, will try more.

Comment: The question is if variable set by Travis is readable via `System.env`. On Jenkins it is. It might also another problem. You need to check on Travis what exactly `sonatypeRepo` property returns. If it's present in `gradle.properties` and it's empty it might pass, because it's present.

Comment: @Opal Indeed. Setting the parameter with the above elvis var constructor makes it pass. I'm still unsure if Travis reads the variable.

Comment: `print` the result of `System.env` to std out.

Answer (score 24):

I just stumbled on this too.

This is how I got it to work:

In my build.gradle

```
def uzer = hasProperty('blahUser') ? blahUser : System.getenv('blahUser')
def creds = hasProperty('blahPwd') ? blahPwd : System.getenv('blahPwd')
```

In my $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties

```
blahUser=batman
blahPwd=eatsworms
```

So I needed this for travis-ci -- which I don't think has a notion of a $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties    But you can add environment variables to .travis.yml.

Basically, as previously mentioned, if the property is 'there'; gradle uses it, otherwise asks the environment for it.  In my case the 'hasProperty()' check was needed so travis wouldn't generate a property not found exception.....

hth...

Comment: I had to use project.hasProperties() in my build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Below an example to define a project property, not a local variable, if it is not defined, by getting the value from the Environment.

```
project.ext {
    if (! project.hasProperty('some_prop')) { 
        some_prop = System.getenv('some_prop') 
    }
}
```

I wanted a project property so I can use it also to set the PWs in my spring-boot YAML file... both locally and in CI.