# How can I reference a Travis secure variable in my build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, environment-variables, travis-ci

One of my project dependencies sits on a private Bintray repo, which requires a username and password to access. Locally, I have these set in my `gradle.properties`:

```
bintrayUsername=<myUserName>
bintrayPassword=<myPass>
```

This works (locally), where `hasProperty(X)` resolves true and it uses this property:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        def mahBintrayUsername = hasProperty(bintrayUsername) ? bintrayUsername : System.getenv('bintrayUsername')
        def mahBintrayPassword = hasProperty(bintrayPassword) ? bintrayPassword : System.getenv('bintrayPassword')


        maven {
            credentials {
                username mahBintrayUsername
                password mahBintrayPassword
            }
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/my-repo-org/maven-private'
        }
    }
}
```

On Travis, I use [secure variables](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Secure-Variables) so I don't have to expose these values in my public repo, but with the aim of being able to build directly from my public repo. When the build starts, you can see that the variables are exported:

```
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export bintrayUsername=[secure]
$ export bintrayPassword=[secure]
$ export TERM=dumb

...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/home/travis/build/ataulm/wutson/build.gradle' line: 15
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'wutson'.
> Could not find property 'bintrayUsername' on repository container.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
```

I'm unsure how to reference the exported environment variables in my `build.gradle` such that they would be found.

I've checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023884/travis-ci-environment-variables-with-gradle-properties) which doesn't seem to work (as above), as well as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023884/travis-ci-environment-variables-with-gradle-properties#comment40762174_26023884) which results in the same build failure.

The series of commits I've tried can be seen here, with the latest: https://github.com/ataulm/wutson/commit/9331b8d91b4acf11fd3e286ff8ba1a24ed527177

Comment: The property should be available as `System.env.bintrayUsername`. Using the elvis operator will return in an error because accessing an unknown property throws an exception rather than simply returning null. If you want to conditionally resolve the value as a project property vs environment variable you'll have to do something like `hasProperty('bintrayUsername') ? bintrayUsername : System.env.bintrayUsername`.

Comment: Hi @mark, I tried this (removing the dollar symbol) but same build failure. I didn't follow what you said in the 2nd part of your comment - I _do_ conditionally check (unless I misunderstand).

Comment: Looking at your example above I think you may just be missing quotes. Note that `hasProperty()` takes a `String` argument.

Comment: If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept! +1 if you can also suggest a way to avoid this error, or suggest how to debug this myself in a logical fashion where I will inevitably forget that `hasProperty()` takes a string, in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is a result of your ternary statement attempting to evaluate `bintrayUsername` as part of the condition.

The `hasProperty()` method takes a `String` argument so you should use `hasProperty('bintrayUsername')`, instead of `hasProperty(bintrayUsername)`. Doing the latter will attempt to evaluate a property that may not exist, leading to the `MissingPropertyException`.

Simply remember that trying to evaluate any symbol that doesn't exist will typically result in a `MissingPropertyException`.

Answer (score 0):

Below an example to define a project property -not a local variable- if it is not defined, by getting the value from the Environment, i.e. where Travis puts your secure variable.

```
project.ext {
    if (! project.hasProperty('some_prop')) { 
        some_prop = System.getenv('some_prop') 
    }
}
```

If you never set it as a property (not using gradle.properties files) and you always want to set it from the environment, just remove the IF part. :)

Note: I wanted a project property so I can use it also to set values in my spring-boot YAML file... both locally and in CI.